# individual research grants

Tags: funding, postdocs, terminology, canada

I am going to apply for some postdoc positions in Canada. I have some feedback from professor. They are saying about availability of individual research grants in their department. I do not know how this type of grants means?

Comment: You should ask them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name suggests, individual research grants correspond to funding which can be awarded to an individual researcher (often a junior researcher). It usually covers their own salary, possibly also equipment and some travel/conferences budget.

Generally one has to apply by proposing a specific research project in a host institution, and the grant is awarded depending on the quality of the project.